# Using time dimension in Geoserver WMTS

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

Is, there a way to use the time dimension in Geoserver/Geowebcache WMTS endpoints ? I have this working for WMS, but time seems to have no effect on WMTS calls.

Example URL: http://some-host:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=tfmsh%3AECHO_TOP_FORECAST&style=&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A3857&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A3857%3A4&TileCol=3&TileRow=6&time=2019-07-11T20:10:00.000Z

The reason I want WMTS is because I need URLS I can cache in nginx, so bounding boxes in WMS requests are making that impossible. I'm using Leaflet js as a web map client.

Thanks for any help, I've never used WMTS before.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Leaflet will make the same WMS requests (since the tile bounding boxes are deterministic) so they can be cached safely.

Comment: I've found bounding boxes are not deterministic. At the same zoom level, I will get differences in bounding box coordinates. So start at zoom level 10, zoom to 11, back to 10 you will see different bbox coords.

Comment: The bboxes (and therefore, the WMS `getMap` URLs) [look deterministic enough to me when using a `L.TileLayer.WMS`](https://plnkr.co/edit/fsB4Cwu1SuwLzync).

Comment: Thank you for that plunker sample. Using your technique I was able to determine my problem is with the nonTiledLayer plugin. Using that plugin the bbox is not deterministic. I had started using that to have smoother weather animations without tiles. My mistake. Using standard leaflet I see the same results you described.